# how to fix fabook js like code so it accesses facebook with either http or https

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

On my website http://stokesabode.com I have installed the Facebook Js like code using async.  Although it appears to be working correctly Google page speed testing reports I should

```
Serve resources from a consistent URL
```

along with the resulting error that I am accessing facebook using both non secure and secure http.

I am using the Facebook code generator that provided:

```
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.async=true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=my application id number";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

In testing I found that if I remove either:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=my application id number";
```

or

```
(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
```

and rerunning the test the error would disappear and my page speed score will jump up.  How can I fix this error so I am only accessing facebook in secure https mode?